# Eclipse Neon RCP - Fixed Layout Views

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

Our software is based on Eclipse's RCP platform. We did develop it using Eclipse Indigo and as we migrated to Neon a few days ago the following problem occured: The views in the layout are not fixed anymore (they can be dragged around, minimized and closed) even though I set

```
layout.setFixed(true);
```

Does anyone have an idea why's that? If you need any further information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse 4 the implementation of `setFixed` does nothing.

This is sort of described in Eclipse bug [331402](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331402)

The suggestion in that bug is to not include the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt` plug-in in your RCP build - this will stop all drag and drop of parts.

Comment: Well, if I exclude that plugin, the software does not start. It says "No Application ID found" and a dialog pops up saying "missing constraint require-bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt"